# Session 'app': Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I am working on Android studio 3.5.2 version.
It was working fine yesterday. But today even the blank activity is not running on my physical device- Xiaomi Redmi 4. I have updated driver, restarted Android Debug Bridge, USB Debugging is ON, even troubleshooted. I have checked for any updates, it is updated. Instant run is off. Many times I have done "clean project" and "Rebuild project". It is taking too much time to run on my device, hence device is getting timed out. Earlier, this was not the problem. What to do? Why this sudden problem out of nowhere?

Comment: File -> Invalidate cache and Restart android studio will do the work for you and try again once!

Comment: Still not working. Tried and tested. @PrajwalW

Comment: Try this: Try killing and restarting the adb with adb kill-server and adb start-server

Comment: Restarting adb worked for me. Thanx @PrajwalW

Comment: Pls do accept the below ans so that others can get the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Try killing and restarting the adb with `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`.

Answer (score 0):

This also occurs when your phone is falling short on internal storage space please check that before running the app on it

Answer (score 0):

for real device, I restart my device and its work properly without restart android studio.